# Running karmajs tests from Jenkins on Mac v10.7 Lion

Tags: javascript, jenkins, continuous-integration, karma-runner

I'm trying to setup jenkins CI to run karma js ( which in turn runs Jasmine unit tests ) on Mac mini with osx Lion.

When I run in from terminal on mac it works well 
(Starts karma server on localhost:9876, open up chrome/safari, execute tests and exits with status 0 when all tests passed.)

It also works when in run it by ssh from windows ( SSH to mac and then 'karma start myconfigfile.js' )

But it doesn't run correctly when it's started by jenkins CI:

In jenkins I have build step:

Execute shell:

```
#!/bin/bash -ex
karma start client/config/ci-unittest.conf.js
```

In the jenkis console output I can see it starts karma correctly, run the browser, but it's not serving all resolved js files and the browser doesn't execute tests (`Chrome 28.0 (Mac): Executed 0 of 0 DISCONNECTED (0.165 secs / 0 secs`)

Here is console output, when it runs correct from terminal/ssh:
http://pastebin.com/2YvbLB1b

And here is console output from jenkins:
http://pastebin.com/tbURAvUt

All I can see is that karma started from jenkins is not serving all of resolved files to browser.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: There was a problem in some version of chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=422218